# Invalid regular expression error in snowflake

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I'm trying to extract date (20200222) from filename while copyinto command in snowflake.

**File Name**

s3://hadoop/2020002/dbo.DOSSIER_TRANSPORT_**20200222**.csv.gz

**snowflake query**

```
SELECT regexp_substr(metadata$filename, '/(_((\-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).)/' as data FROM '@PRD.OPE_STG
                                                _CMD.SPX_PRD_CMD/' (file_format => 'OTS_TEST.OPA_STG_BENE.OTD_FORMAT', pattern => '.*dbo.DOSSIER_TRANSPORT.*') ;
```

I tried this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/sI7bW4/157) but its not supporting in snowflake. Getting below error

```
100048 (2201B): Invalid regular expression: '/(_((-|+)?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).)/', no argument for repetition operator: +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(metadata$filename, '_([0-9]+)[.]', 1, 1, 'c', 1)
```

This is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/72Zntp/2)

The pattern matches `_`, then captures one or more digits in Group 1 and then matches `.`. Since the `group_num` argument is `1`, the return value is Group 1 value.

Comment: Try also with `_([0-9]+)[.][A-Za-z0-9.]*$` if your strings might be trickier.

Comment: this solution works for if filename is like this fact_reserve_20190802.csv.gz. What if the file name is like this fact_reserve_20190803_001.csv.gz and I want to grep 8digits number between underscore and dot

Comment: @marjun Maybe `_([0-9]{8})[_.]`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/72Zntp/4).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double escapes with Snowflake.  If you just select your regexp string you will get:

```
SELECT '/(_((\-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).)/';
=>   /(_((-|+)?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).)/
```

which is exactly what the regexp function will get as an input argument as well.
With double escapes you get:

```
SELECT '/(_((\\-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?).)/';
=>   /(_((\-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).)/
```

which is what I believe you want.

The error you get is from the regexp `(-|+)`; the `+` operator needs a real argument...

Comment: If you want to match an operator character you can also use eg `[+]` instead of `\\+`